# most recent values entered for a column in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have an access query and have to convert it into SQL Server 2012.

The query looks as below I need to convert it into access

```
SELECT col1, 
    col2, col3, 
    col4, col5, 
    Last(col6), Last(col7) ,
    last(col8), col9, col10 
  INTO [Temp 2] 
FROM f4
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3,col4, col5, col8, col9
HAVING (col8='529')
   AND (trim(col9) in ('S','W'))
   AND (trim(col10)  in ('301','302','303','305','311','313','319','9101'))
```

Comment: You converted an access query to Sql Server 2012, and you now want it converted to access?

Comment: So what is the problem you have? Do you get an error?

Comment: T-SQL has no `LAST` function, nor is it simple to implement since it goes against the idea of rowsets being unordered. Can you give an example of input and your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

try to use sql server IMPORT tool. that may help you do your conversion with minimum work. You may find Imports in :

```
Right click on your DB in SQL Server/ Select Tasks/ Select Import Data
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what little there is, I'm going to take a stab and say:

```
SELECT col1, 
    col2, col3, 
    col4, col5, 
    Max(col6), Max(col7) ,
    Max(col8), col9, col10 
  INTO [Temp 2] 
FROM f4
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3,col4, col5, col9, col10
HAVING (col8='529')
   AND (ltrim(rtrim(col9)) in ('S','W'))
   AND (ltrim(rtrim(col10))  in ('301','302','303','305','311','313','319','9101'))
```

SQL has no Last or Trim functions, so I'm assuming you want Max and I added the ltrim(rtrim()) functionality (which replaces VBA's Trim() functionality).  Also, I don't think you can Group By Col8 if you're taking the Max of it.